# Are messages in an AWS SQS batch processed in parallel by Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a question that I can't seem to find the answer to online.

I'll ask the question in the form of an example as follows:

Let's say I have a FIFO Queue. The Queue receives 10 messages. I have a Lambda function that is subscribed to said Queue that is pulling from the Queue with batch size of 5.

Now, are my understandings of SQS correct when I say...

1. The Lambda function will be invoked twice.
2. The second invocation will start running after the first is complete.
3. Each invocation will process 5 messages, each of which will be processed at the same time (in parallel).

Are all of these statements correct? If not, which are incorrect and why?

I have read the SQS documentation but not seeing anything that mentions all of the above statements.

Comment: Does [this](https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a/2019/11/20/sqs-fifo3-734x1024.png) help explain things? AKA. it depends on the `MessageGroupId`s you have.

Comment: Yes! That helps a lot. I didn't even know about MessageGroupID's. Where do you even set those?

Comment: Read more about them [here in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html) :) you can set them using the relative SDKs / API / console, they are specific to FIFO queues.

Comment: But I am also still wondering, in that photo, are `C5,C4,C3,C2, and C1` processed all at the same time or one after the other?

Comment: They are processed one after another in the respective Lambda instance, otherwise a FIFO queue wouldn't be needed 

Comment: You are more than welcome, feel free to answer your own question :)

Comment: See also: [amazon web services - AWS SQS FIFO - How to get more than 10 messages at a time? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661834/aws-sqs-fifo-how-to-get-more-than-10-messages-at-a-time)

Comment: #2 - not quite: the 2nd Lambda invocation starts after the first batch of 5 messages has been deleted, not after the 1st Lambda invocation has completed, afaik. The Lambda could delete all 5 messages long before the Lambda invocation ends, for example. #3 - no, SQS batches with the same message ID won't be processed concurrently.

Comment: What if the Queue was Standard and not FIFO? Would all messages in batch with same ID be processed concurrently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of comments, I now understand what I need for my solution.

Assuming batch size of 5.

Assuming that all messages have the same Message Group ID, the messages will be consumed in batches (of 5) from SQS. This means 2 invocations of the Lambda function.

Each message in batch will be processed one after the other, hence FIFO.