# AWS SQS - Process items in a batch within a single Lambda (FIFO)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS FIFO setup with a Lambda event trigger. From my understanding with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257232/are-messages-in-an-aws-sqs-batch-processed-in-parallel-by-lambda-function), it appears that, when SQS processes a batch of messages, the lambda triggered would process the items *one message at a time*. In my use case, however, I need it to process all the items in the batch *as a group*. Is that possible to setup on an SQS Event Source?

Context: let's say my batch size is 2. In my tests, it's indeed triggering the lambda when it receives those two message. However, it processes them individually (i.e., one message in `event.Records` array). I want it so when the lambda triggers, it processes both of them together (i.e., two messages in `event.Records`).

More context: this is how it looks when the lambda is triggered. It uses the same lambda but the contents of `event.Records` is only one.
[image: part 1]
[image: part 2]

Comment: Are you sure that `event.Records` only has a single entry? It should have two records. Please show us your evidence that it contains only one record.

Comment: The AWS documentation(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) suggests that `Lambda polls up to 10 messages in your queue at once`. Could you please share how you have configured your Lambda function ?

Comment: The linked answer is _not_ saying that one message is passed to the Lambda function per invocation. It is saying that the Lambda function should process the provided messages in order, so that FIFO is retained. The Lambda function in that answer is being passed 5 messages.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein have added screenshots as requested to show the single run but the messages are split individually.

Comment: @Chaitanya my event source is configured in CDK so it has a batch size of 2.

Comment: The answer linked has the bit that says *will be processed one after the other* as well.

Comment: Yes, that invocation of the Lambda function was passed only one message. Did you send 2 messages to the queue? If so, it should either invoke the Lambda function once with two messages, or twice with one message each time.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yup, I sent the message to the queue within minutes of each other. The good news is, the lambda is triggered as soon as I send the 2nd message. The bad news, it's seeing the message as individual ones.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's seeing the message as individual ones"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253162/discussion-between-jayg-code-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for low-volume queues, *we're not guaranteed to get the same amount of items* every time Lambda pulls messages from SQS. https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/324#issuecomment-151322134

It only thus works if you have a consistent large volume of messages in your queue. There is a hacky way of implementing it without setting up SQS as an event source: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/324#issuecomment-258557413